# running a python script with ptemcee (a package of Monte Carlo) in SBATCH / SLURM

Tags: python, slurm, montecarlo, sbatch, emcee

I need to run a python script using **sbatch / slurm** The script works until the step which it must use the **ptemcee** (i.e. runs a monte carlo markov chain). In this step, nothing happens (as if the script fell in a infinite loop). I know that there is no mistake in the script because when I run it out of the slurm, it works ok.
Someone knows what should I do to run a ptemcee (or emcee) in sbatch / slurm ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#SBATCH -J Exemplo            # Nome do job
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=15
#SBATCH --ntasks 1           # Numero total de processos
#SBATCH --partition=batch 

#bash bash.sh
module load python
srun python teste.py
date
```

Answer (score 0):

hope you solved this a while ago, but I've been running ptemcee via slurm using `#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=48` - so your submission script would be

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    #SBATCH -J Exemplo #Nome do job
    #SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=48
    #SBATCH --partition=batch
```

If I remember correctly, if you request the wrong resources, the script takes an extremely long time to run, as you're essentially running your script on one CPU. Perhaps that's why your script hangs.